# Using a username/AD group name as a Crystal Report Parameter on BusinessObjects

Tags: crystal-reports, active-directory, business-intelligence, business-objects

I've got a parametrized report built with Crystal running on a BusinessObjects server.
I would like to get the report to auto-populate the location parameter based on the user name or Active Directory group name.

How do I implement this logic? Ideally I'd have a lookup in the report itself going if AD Group= Kansas Workers then parameter=Kansas...

Looking for any solution that will not require me creating a separate report for every location and placing them in different folders on BO....

Comment: Which version of BusinessObjects are you using and is it Crystal Reports for Enterprise or Crystal Reports 2011/13/16?

Comment: @Kristof I am using CR Standart Ver 11.5
And I think I've found what I am looking for by using CurrentCEUserName function, although that only provides me with a username from the BusinessObjects and not any group information, so I will have to build some reference tables to reference names to locations...
Would be great if there was another solution